# The space of conformal classes of the $n-$sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

It is well-known that the space of conformal classes on the $2-$sphere is just a point. What is known about the space of conformal classes on the $n-$sphere? Is there any structure on it?

Comment: Infinite dimensional, since you can use purely local compactly supported deformations of the conformal geometry to construct arbitrary conformal invariants at a point.

Comment: Thank you! Does there exist a collection of conformal invariants on the sphere which determines a conformal class uniquely?